# Adding points to map with Leaflet using .forEach function

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json

Trying to add an array of points to a map with a Leaflet with `.forEach`.

I thought this should work, but alas, it does not:

```js
var jsonData = [
  {
    "LNG":-75.16472099534634,
    "LAT":40.034508187448395,
    "NAME": "Resto1"
  },
  {
    "LNG":-75.17898120530263,
    "LAT":40.06738292573648,
    "NAME": "Resto2"
  }]


var addMarkers = function(point) {
      L.marker([point.LAT, point.LNG])
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(point.NAME);
};

jsonData.forEach(addMarkers);
```

I understand I can do it like this:

```
var addMarkers = function(map) {
  for (var point in jsonData) {
     L.marker([jsonData[point].LAT, jsonData[point].LNG])
        .addTo(map)
```

But was hoping to do it more functionally. Any hints?

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Loop through Leaflet Map layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748875/loop-through-leaflet-map-layers). It was suggested to made `jsonData.forEach(addMarkers);` break on `return false`.

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on when I first posted this. But my own solution `jsonData.forEach(addMarkers);` appears to be working when I try again. I think I just had some leakage going on.

Comment: (But thanks for the tip @Taras)